# What experiments on humans could possibly go wrong and cause these side effects?

Tags: biology

I'm developing a society that uses methods of mind control and scientific enhancements on their military force and does extensive experimentation on test subjects without their consent. These include mind control, truth serums, torture experiments and controversial medical and biological tests.

The society's work force live in a walled city divided into districts and have done so for several generations and none of the current population remember what it was like to be free or live outside of the city. As the military also takes the role of the police force their primary job is to enforce the government's requirements on the population and to punish offenders. Many offenders find themselves undergoing extensive mind control and then are placed into military service.

Naturally the government scientists are constantly performing experiments (they have no ethical issues with experimenting on humans) and of course sometimes these experiments fail. These experiments are performed on "guinea pigs" before they are used on the military force (The guinea pigs are normally prisoners, etc). Sometimes the victim dies and sometimes they are severely mutated.

To add dramatic elements to my story I want these mutants to be released outside the city's walls instead of being destroyed and for them to have the appearance of black zombie-like creatures (not necessarily have all the characteristics of a zombie) that are extremely mobile.

Since this society is fairly advanced (50 to 100 years ahead of us) it could be that this particular strand of mutants could be from past experiments before the government got to its current state of knowledge.

My question is this:

**What experiments on humans could possibly fail in such a way that could produce mutants with the appearance of zombie like creature that are still mobile?**

Comment: I don't believe that questions about "methods of mind control and scientific enhancements" can really be [tag:science-based] now. Scientifically, it pretty much ain't gonna happen, unless you have specific way in mind, like electric brain stimulation implants?.. But first, tell us how you got telepathy to work. Only when we know it, we could guess what experiments would make sense.

Comment: Zombie like as in no tought procces, no conscience, no regard to self harm, and a desire to eat humans?

Comment: @Mołot well you almost guessed it. Implants in the individuals that allow them to communicate via thought to a central control and vice versa

Comment: @Ovi in this case they defiantly have a desire to kill anything living. I only used "zombie like" to describe them as I couldn't think of any other term.

Comment: Then sorry... [Brain implants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_implant) are here long time and there is no feasible way to make them cause mutations. All kind of psychological trauma, social dysfunctions etc, yes, but not mutations. These simply do nothing at all with genes. At best, can be carcinogenic. This happened. But carcinogenic implants make people die. And that's it.

Comment: @Mołot the implants where specifically for telepathic communication. I have edited my question so hopefully that helps

Comment: To be fair, I really disliked the "black zombie" constraint.

Comment: @ThalesPereira forget that one then and come up with something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brains**

Failed experiments on psychological enhancement left the prisoner with holes in their brains (taking things out is easier than adding things). **Prisoner is left with no moral reasoning** (no conscience/sense of wrong), **and *very* easily agitated**. No fiction needed here, [a lot of killers today](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXMnc2Xjj-o) have some kind of physical brain damage.

**Brawn**

Some of the torture involved could increase the prisoner's physique (e.g. in the famous "Power of One" novel, a kid was often forced to hold a heavy bar for as long as he could. In the end, he became very strong from it).

Another source of physical enhancement is all the bio/medical testing of combat enhancement drugs. Maybe some combination of them left permanent effects.

**Dumped outside the city**

So your government is doing awful things. Someone complains. New law says "you can't kill the subjects when you are done with them". The government lab starts throwing prisoners live into rubbish chutes that dump outside the city.

End result: Angry, insensitive, less-intelligent, buff humanoids being dumped outside the city gates.

Comment: And then just and some extensive bruising or haemorrhaging to cause the black appearance. I like it.

Comment: Yea if you want to make them seem less human, maybe one chemical went wrong and dyed their skin black or purple, and they are covered with scars from experiments and also from their own self harm, with all that fury they have.

Comment: The interesting thought experiment here is when do you cross the line between angry human and "zombies"? In our minds, zombies are no longer human, so we no longer have any qualms killing them. We would probably still kill murderous-tortured-psychopaths, but we'd feel differently about it.

Comment: One more thing about these men/creatures—they're not contagious (like zombies) or reproducing (like orcs/monsters), so the only growth in population is the rubbish chute pumping them out.

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest genetic experiments trying to infuse people with animal DNA in order to create lower intelligence but physical powerful soldiers. Those experiments go wrong sometimes creating creatures that are either so vicious that they are untrainable or twisted and broken in some way that makes them non-viable as soldiers.

Those creatures are released outside the walls for two reasons:

1. They can be tracked and monitored to see if any do prove to be viable or even manage to reproduce in the wild.
2. They act as a deterrent for anyone from inside or from outside the city to travel through the area.

Comment: The second reason as to why they where dumped outside the city was partly the reason.